# Xamarin iOS App crashes immediately after startup

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've got a Xamarin app, which runs as expected for a while and then, after a couple of days just crashes immediately after trying to start it. Here's the output from the XCode Console filtered by the app's package name.

```
default 12:54:58.536319 +0200   SpringBoard Bootstrapping foo.bar.MyApp with intent foreground-interactive
default 12:54:58.539833 +0200   assertiond  Submitting new job for "foo.bar.MyApp" on behalf of <BKProcess: 0x102877f50; SpringBoard; com.apple.springboard; pid: 15264; agency: SystemShell; visibility: foreground; task: running>
default 12:54:58.540033 +0200   assertiond  Submitted job with label: UIKitApplication:foo.bar.MyApp[0x44cf][62]
default 12:54:58.580322 +0200   assertiond  Unable to get pid for 'UIKitApplication:foo.bar.MyApp[0x44cf][62]': No such process (3)
error   12:54:58.580490 +0200   assertiond  Failed to start job with error <NSError: 0x10288ff30; domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain; code: 3; reason: "No such process"> {
    description = "Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:foo.bar.MyApp[0x44cf][62]";
    failureReason = "No such process";
    userInfo = {
        BKLaunchdJobLabel = UIKitApplication:foo.bar.MyApp[0x44cf][62];
        BKLaunchdOperation = launch_get_running_pid_4SB;
    }
}
default 12:54:58.580757 +0200   assertiond  Deleted job with label: UIKitApplication:foo.bar.MyApp[0x44cf][62]
error   12:54:58.582916 +0200   SpringBoard [foo.bar.MyApp] Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 0x283076850; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Failed to start job">
error   12:54:58.583057 +0200   SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10b1768b0; foo.bar.MyApp; pid: -1> with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID foo.bar.MyApp" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID foo.bar.MyApp, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x2832f7e10 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={BKLaunchdOperation=launch_get_running_pid_4SB, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get pid for label UIKitApplication:foo.bar.MyApp[0x44cf][62], BKLaunchdJobLabel=UIKitApplication:foo.bar.MyApp[0x44cf][62], NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process}}, BKSProcessJobLabel=UIKitApplication:foo.bar.MyApp[0x44cf][62], BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}
default 12:54:58.583151 +0200   SpringBoard Adding: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10b1768b0; foo.bar.MyApp; pid: -1>
default 12:54:58.583303 +0200   SpringBoard <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10b1768b0; foo.bar.MyApp; pid: -1> exited.
default 12:54:58.584241 +0200   SpringBoard Removing: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10b1768b0; foo.bar.MyApp; pid: -1>
default 12:54:58.591967 +0200   SpringBoard Application process state changed for foo.bar.MyApp: <SBApplicationProcessState: 0x283c6a420; pid: -1; taskState: Not Running; visibility: Unknown>
default 12:54:58.592169 +0200   SpringBoard Process exited: <FBApplicationProcess: 0x10b1768b0; foo.bar.MyApp; pid: -1> -> <FBApplicationProcessExitContext: 0x2832cbe10; exitReason: (none); terminationReason: (none)> {
    stateAtExit = <FBProcessState: 0x283c38060; pid: -1; taskState: Unknown; visibility: Unknown>;
}
default 12:54:58.592395 +0200   SpringBoard Application process state changed for foo.bar.MyApp: (null)
default 12:54:58.838065 +0200   SpringBoard Front display did change: <SBApplication: 0x2803522b0; foo.bar.MyApp>
```

I observed that this phenomenon always happens after a certain amount of days, which keeps me thinking that there's some certificate or something similar, which expired in the meanwhile.

Q: Is there such a thing and how can I ensure that it's longer valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing your application on a real device and using free provisioning profile? If so, it could be a certificate issue.

There're some limitations when you are using free provisioning profile. One of them is:

> Provisioning profiles created with free provisioning will expire after
>   one week, and signing identities will expire after one year.

Refer to this documentation for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=windows#limitations.

When it has been expired, you have to use Visual Studio to generate a new ipa for deploying your app on a real device.

Comment: Indeed I use free provisioning. That must be it. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @mefiX You're welcome. If you felt this helpful for you, please accept it as an answer.